# FormCollection MVC5 not passing decimal to controller

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

i keep getting errors when trying to post an `<input type="number">` from my view to my controller using `FormCollection`.  the database type for expenseBackup is a `decimal(8,2)`.  I keep getting `"Cannot impliticity convert string to decimal?".`  Then when i try `expenseBackup = Int32.Parse(formValues["expenseBackup"])`, i get `"Input string was not in correct format"`.  i don't want to have to convert anything in the controller i don't understand why it won't just pass as a decimal through the FormCollection.

Controller

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(FormCollection formValues)
        {
            var data = new usr_ebillingClientDatabase()
            {
                client = formValues["client"], //is a string from form
                expenseBackup = formValues["expenseBackup"] //is a decimal from form
            };
            dataContext.table1.InsertOnSubmit(data);
            try
            {
                dataContext.SubmitChanges();                    
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }           
        }
```

View

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.expenseBackup, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" , , @type="number", @step=".01" } })
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

when you're reading the field from `formValues["expenseBackup"]` it's being read as a string. Convert it to a decimal using `Convert.ToDecimal()`.

```
expenseBackup = Convert.ToDecimal(formValues["expenseBackup"] ?? 0m);
```

Comment: thx...works if there's a value, but what if expenseBackup is null?  i get `input string was not in correct format`

Comment: The edit will default null to zero - what do you want to do with null?

Comment: thx...would prefer to not input 0's into my db would rather nulls.  i implemented something similar `expenseBackup = Convert.ToDecimal(formValues["expenseBackup"] == "" ? 0 :  formValues["expenseBackup"]);` but when i tried to replace the 0 with null, it gave me the input string error from above.  i know this is elementary, it just seems like a roundabout way to handle a db insert from a form post.  do you recommend the form collection approach or strongly type everything in the post back to the controller (how i used to handle forms).  sorry if i'm getting off topic :)

Comment: I've always used a dedicated viewmodel, so strongly typed. You're effectively having to hard code your form values anyway when putting `["expenseBackup"]`- why not just make a View Model and then you can specify that it handles nulls. eg `decimal? ExpenseBackup {get; set;}` ?

Comment: As for your issue entering nulls to the database that's hard for me to answer without knowing the columns restraints, and how you're actually trying to insert the data

Answer (score 1):

[`FormCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.formcollection?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) is a key-value pair collection ([`NameValueCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection(v=vs.110).aspx)) which returns values as string based from provided key, which is also a string. If you're in doubt which number format applied by numeric input during submit, use combination of [`decimal.TryParse()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.2) and if-condition with `string.IsNullOrEmpty()` to check null/empty string value:

```
decimal expense;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(formValues["expenseBackup"]) 
    && decimal.TryParse(formValues["expenseBackup"], out expense))
{
    var data = new usr_ebillingClientDatabase()
    {
        client = formValues["client"],
        expenseBackup = expense
    };

    // insert to database
}
else
{
    // unable to parse numeric value, do something else
}
```

If you're sure that numeric representation passed in `FormCollection` uses certain decimal separator other than default, use [`NumberFormatInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberformatinfo?view=netframework-4.7.2) when parsing with `decimal.Parse()`/`decimal.TryParse()`:

```
var numberFormat = new System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo() { NumberDecimalSeparator = "," };

var data = new usr_ebillingClientDatabase()
{
    client = formValues["client"],
    expenseBackup = decimal.Parse(formValues["expenseBackup"], numberFormat);
};
```

However, I recommend using strongly-typed viewmodel over `FormCollection` because you're using `EditorFor`, and it will pass property values directly to controller when viewmodel name is included as action parameter.

Comment: do you ever use a combination of FormCollection and strongly-typed?  is it "bad" if i handle my string values with FormCollection, but handle the other data formats strongly-typed?  example `[HttpPost] public ActionResult Create(FormCollection formVals, decimal? expense){}`